# How to get Mint Address of of SPL token using associated token account? without rpc call

Tags: solana-program, token, spl-token-program, rustc

I can get an associated token account knowing **the mint address** and **wallet address** with spl_associated_token_account::get_associated_token_address function

But is it possible to get a mint address, when knowing **only the wallet address and associated_token_address**?

for example, if we know
this associated token account CfUzkuDDdUvoBsK4vr134DV7Tb3CADHtsPL4Zs4UuAQs and
its owner's wallet address 7REXxsREHYPbMrxShwRjqAhS5VxWpoCCkzfRicgxrvek

can we get the usdc mint address https://solscan.io/token/EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v ?

or somehow to understand that this associated token account  **is an account for usdc?**

Have to avoid rpc calls for speed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way(short of bruteforce) to get the original inputs that resulted in the SHA-256 hash produced by the `get_associated_token_address` function.

Hence the answer to your question is unfortunately no; there's no way to reverse the derived address to get the mint that produced it.

If you really need to get rid of RPCs, you might want to consider setting up an off-chain index that stores the information you need.

Comment: Maybe you've some repo that could be a good example of such an index? 
thank you!

Comment: I don't have an example but it'll be quite the same as setting up database storage for any other web application.

[This](https://github.com/anoushk1234/anchor-prisma-transpiler) seems like a useful tool for generating db schemas from your anchor-idl. disclaimer: I've never actually used it myself though